# oracle - how to list out the products that are going to expire in 2months time?

Tags: oracle, date

assume all the product expires in 1years

how to list out the products that are going to expire in  2months time?

```
table product
--------------------------------

food    | ManufacturedDate| 
--------------------------------
apple   | 12-nov-11  
orange  | 12-jan-12  
pear    | 12-jan-12  
milk    | 12-nov-11
mango   | 12-nov-11
```

output

```
orange  | 12-jan-12
pear    | 12-jan-12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you data says that the others apart from pear+orange expire today, so assuming you want to exclude expiring today and include those expiring WITHIN 2 months time:

```
SQL> select food, manufacturedate, add_months(manufacturedate,12) expiry_date from product where add_months(manufacturedate, 12) <= add_months(trunc(sysdate), 2) and add_months(manufacturedate, 12) > trunc(sysdate);

FOOD        MANUFACTU EXPIRY_DA
--------------- --------- ---------
orange      12-JAN-12 12-JAN-13
pear        12-JAN-12 12-JAN-13
```

or a more index friendly way of putting it (removing the functions on the column side):

```
SQL> select food, manufacturedate, add_months(manufacturedate,12) expiry_date from product where manufacturedate <= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -10) and manufacturedate > add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12);

FOOD        MANUFACTU EXPIRY_DA
--------------- --------- ---------
orange      12-JAN-12 12-JAN-13
pear        12-JAN-12 12-JAN-13
```

Comment: hi, your code works! do you mind to elaborate on how is works?

Comment: If we take the first statement (the second is the same, its just more index friendly).
`add_months(manufacturedate, 12)`. this means add 12 months to the manufactured date and compare to the current date + 2 months `add_months(trunc(sysdate), 2)` in other words when manufactured+12  months is less than two months from now you want to see the rows.`add_months(manufacturedate, 12) > trunc(sysdate);` this means ignore rows for products that have already expired or will expire today (if you want include expiring today, just change the `>` to `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * 
from product
where add_months( trunc(ManufacturedDate), 12 ) >= trunc(SYSDATE)
and add_months( trunc(ManufacturedDate), 12) <= add_months(trunc(SYSDATE), 2);
```

Comment: `trunc(sysdate)` by default truncates to day. This means that hours, minutes and seconds get reset to 0 so today's date would be 12-NOV-12 00:00:00. You can specify other units. Check [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) for more info.

Comment: i tried in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b589/1)but does not work. it returns 0 count